# How can I add success message after button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

```xml
<template>
    
<div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="firstName"  placeholder="Enter your name">
  </div>
    
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="lastName" placeholder="Enter your last name">
  </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="message">Type Your message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" v-model="message" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
    
  <div class="form-group form-check" v-for="number in numbers" :key="number">
    <input type="checkbox" :value="number.Broj" v-model="checkedNumbers">
    <label class="form-check-label" >{{number.Broj}}</label>
  </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @click="sendMessage">Send message</button>
</div>
</template>
    
<script>
  import http from "../http-common.js";
  import userServices from "../services/userServices.js";
  export default {
    data()
    {
      return {
        firstName: null,
        lastName: null,
        message: null,
        numbers: "",
        checkedNumbers: [], 
      }; 
    },
    methods:
    {
      async sendMessage()
      {
        await http.post("/message", {firstName: this.firstName, lastName: this.lastName, message: this.message, numbers: this.checkedNumbers});
        this.$data.firstName = "",
        this.$data.lastName = "",
        this.$data.checkedNumbers = [],
        this.$data.message = "";
      },
    
      retrieveNumbers() {
        userServices.getNumbers().then(response => {
          this.numbers = response.data;
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
      }
    
    },
    created() {
      this.retrieveNumbers();
    }
  }
    
</script>
```

How can I add success message to the user after clicking Send message button? For example "Message sent"

I have a perfectly working form I can insert data into database and through the form, writing data into text file. using axios after form validation. I am just struggling to show a success message after user clicks the button.

Thank you

Comment: you can use some third party components to show toast messages

Answer (score 0):

You can do something after the Promise is returned, like :

```
await http.post("/message", {firstName: this.firstName, lastName: this.lastName, message: this.message, numbers: this.checkedNumbers}).then((response) => {
  // Do something with the response
})
```

Then, you can pop a swal from [SweetAlert documentation](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) with the message you want to show.

Comment: in part of do something with the response, what should be here?

Comment: If you use SweetAlert2, you could trigger something like this : ```Swal.fire(
  'You clicked the button!', 'success'
)```